# Configuring Entity Framework on a Database Undefined Foreign Key Relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-3.5, entity-relationship, foreign-key-relationship

For a variety of reasons the database that I'm working on (SQL Server 2005) doesn't have any relationships defined. Every table has a primary key. And most tables have at least one foreign key, however we've never configured the constraints.

Can anyone tell me the steps that I should take to inform Entity Framework of the underlying relationships between tables? Is there a particular document that describes this process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to manually create the associations between the tables in your EF model.

In the Entity Framework designer surface, you basically right-click on your table and from the context menu, you need to choose the "Add -> Association" option. In the dialog box that pops up, you can establish the association between your two tables - even without foreign key relationship in the underlying database.

Marc

Comment: Using this method seems to provide only a superficial relationship between entities. The objects are connected, but at the storage level Entity-Framework still has no idea which FK field points to the PK.

Comment: Yes of course - it would be much better to actually add those foreigny key constraints to the database and use them in your EF model.

Comment: I was assuming from how you posted your question that you probably couldn't do that and just wanted to find a way to at least provide some relationships in the EF model.

Comment: It seems like the correct answer is to manually insert the association in the SSDL schema as per the cribsheet that you originally posted.

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/entity-framework-the-cribsheet/

The important piece that I was missing was that I had to manually delete UserID from the child table.

Comment: Just a word of caution - fiddling around with the SSDL might prove a bit dangerous, since the SSDL should really reflect the actual schema as it exists on the database. Changing that manually seems a bit tricky to me - your actual reality and the SSDL suddenly aren't in sync anymore.... Either really change the database (my preferred option), or then just use the "superficial" associations in the conceptual level.